# Testes unitários com NUnit em função com retorno do tipo JsonResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, testes, nunit, testes-unitarios

Estou tentando fazer teste unitário na seguinte função (tem mais ifs, mas acredito que esse trecho seja suficiente para ilustrar), utilizando [NUnit](https://nunit.org). O problema é que não estou conseguindo tratar o retorno do tipo JsonResult. Ao rodar o teste, o resultado é

> Message:   Expected: `True`
>     But was:  `<empty>`

Como posso contornar isso?

Função (está em um Controller):

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult ChangePassword(string password, string new_password, string confirm_password, string email)
    {
        //string email = Seguridad.Session.GetUserMail();

        if (new_password != confirm_password)
            return Json(new { success = false, message = "As senhas não coincidem" });

    }
```

Teste:

```
[TestFixture]
public class CandidatoControllerTestChangePassword
{
    [Test]
    public void TestChangeValidPassword()
    {
        var controller = new CandidatoController();
        var result = controller.ChangePassword("password", "newpassword", "newpassword", "teste@gmail.com") as JsonResult;
        var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.Data);
        var deserializedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(data);

        Assert.AreEqual(true, deserializedData.success);

    }
}
```

Comment: O result.Data retornana o JSON com valor?

Comment: Só com esse if não dá para garantir nada... você está passando duas passwords iguais, o que no código apresentado não retornaria nada...

Answer (score 1):

Você teria que fazer dessa forma:

```
[TestFixture]
public class CandidatoControllerTestChangePassword
{
    [Test]
    public void TestChangeValidPassword()
    {
        var controller = new CandidatoController();
        var result = controller.ChangePassword("password", "newpassword", "newpassword", "teste@gmail.com") as JsonResult;
        var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.Data);

        //O Tipo aqui é dynamic e não 'var' e DeserializeObject não precisa do tipo entre <>
        dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data);

        //Realiza a conversão antes
        bool resultado = false;
        bool.TryParse(json.success.ToString() out resultado);

        //Apenas compara o valor de resultado no AreEqual
        Assert.AreEqual(true, resultado);

    }
}
```

Comment: apareceu um erro "O operador as deve ser usado com um tipo de referência ou tipo anulável ("bool" é um tipo de valor não-anulável)"

Comment: verifique se o success está escrito da forma correta, exemplo: caso na objeto esteja escrito com letra maiúscula (Success) da mesma forma de ser utilizar no objeto dynamic, por se um objeto dynamic você só pegar esse tipo erro em tempo de execução